# Why set primitive type value to zero in the end of move constructor function

Tags: c++

```
MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&& other)

   : _data(nullptr)

   , _length(0)
{
   std::cout << "In MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&&). length = " 
             << other._length << ". Moving resource." << std::endl;

   _data = other._data;
   _length = other._length;

   // Release the data pointer from the source object so that
   // the destructor does not free the memory multiple times.
   other._data = nullptr;
   other._length = 0;
}
```

Here is an example from Microsoft msdn.
It's size_t and can't be free. So you don't have to assign it to 0.
Why set other._length to 0?
THX

Comment: Perhaps for state consistency? It's weird to have an object with a null data pointer but non-zero length.

Comment: Look at `MemoryBlock(const MemoryBlock& other)` and see if it would be correct to assign to a moved object if `other._length` was not reset.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake, no specific technical reason as far as I know. `other` will be destroyed when exiting its scope, since you defined it as an rvalue reference in the move constructor.

You have to make sure to leave rvalue references in move constructors/assignments in a *destructable* state, which is the case by assigning `nullptr` to `_data` (in general you must assure that pointers point to `null`). The `_length = 0` is just for completeness (or habit): The data is moved, data pointer is nulled and the length must be zero.

Answer (score 0):

It's often a good idea to do that, so you can maintain a stricter invariant, making other parts of the class easier to reason about, and require less if checks. To take a concrete example, suppose MemoryBlock had a length() method that returned length. If you didn't set _length on move, then this length() method would require an if check on _data not being null. By setting it to zero after move, this method can just trivially return _length.

Answer (score 0):

After you move the contents of an object A to another object B, A is still around.  It will be destroyed at the end of the scope and, in the meantime, it can be used again.  You can't really count on what the contents of A are after they have been moved, but you can assign a new value to it.  For example, this is legitimate code:

```
std::string a = "Some string";
std::cout << "a before move: " << a << endl;
std::string b = std::move(a);
std::cout << "a after move: " << a << endl;
std::cout << "b after move: " << b << endl;
a = "Some other string";
std::cout << "a after reassignment: " << a << endl;
```

It produces this under Visual Studio:

```
a before move: Some string
a after move:
b after move: Some string
a after reassignment: Some other string
```